# How to show SDWebimage for background Colour in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, sdwebimage

SDWebImage is great library for conversion URL to image. Its working great. But, I have following issue

> // For imageview, we are setting like
>
> ```
> eventImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
>
>     // but, for Image as UIColor,
>
> Showing compiler error if I use like following
>
> self.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageUrl), placeholderImage:UIImage(named: "placeholder.png")))
> ```
>
> even I tried like following
>
> ```
>     let imageBG = sd_setImage(with: URL(string: image), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
>
>     self.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: imageBG)
> ```
>
> and its showing following error
>
> Use of unresolved identifier 'sd_setImage'

Can anyone suggest me for how to fix this?

Comment: create one UIimage and apply that image to pattern image

Comment: I tried that too, showing Use of unresolved identifier 'sd_setImage

Comment: @AnilkumariOSdeveloper where is `scrollView` ?

Comment: please check updated question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `SDWebImageManager` to download image at first and then use it in `UIColor(patterImage:)` constructor.
Try code below:

```
 SDWebImageManager.shared().loadImage(with: URL(string: imageUrl), options: [], progress: nil, completed: { (image, data, error, cacheType, success, url) in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        guard let image = image else {                            
                            return
                        }
                        self.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
                    }
                })
```

Comment: is there possibility to make this method globally, I have to call this method multiple places/classes

Answer (score 0):

That's happens because `sd_setImage` a *UIImageView* method (`eventImageView` should be a `UIImageView`), the [init(patternImage:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/1621933-init) declaration is:

```
init(patternImage image: UIImage)
```

which means that `patternImage` parameter is a `UIImage` *not* `UIImageView`.

To solve this, you should first load the image view, once the loading has done you could assign the color to be the `image` of the image view:

```
eventImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png")) { (image, error, cache, url) in
      self.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
}
```

Or (without the placeholder):

```
eventImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageUrl)) { (image, error, cache, url) in
      self.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
}
```

Comment: but, even I tried to call like above you suggested, while calling run time, showing nil

Comment: If both are not in same place, how to get call this? and if its different images, this won't work.

Comment: @AnilkumariOSdeveloper could you explain what do you mean?

Comment: Suppose, I am using background color with image one function, and Imageview.image is in another function, but as you suggested, eventimageview passing with url for conversion image, and using that image as background color.

Answer (score 0):

`sd_setImage(with` is applicable to `UIImageView`

**Create struct as -**

```
  struct ImageSetter {
        static func setImage(scrollView: UIScrollView,myImageView: UIImageView,imageUrl: URL,placeHolderImage: UIImage){
            myImageView.sd_setImage(with: imageUrl, placeholderImage: placeHolderImage, options: [], completed: { (imageBackground, error, cache, url) in
                scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(patternImage: imageBackground ?? UIImage(named: "place-holder-image")!)
            })
        }
    }
```

**Use -**

```
ImageSetter.setImage(scrollView: scrollView, myImageView: testImageView, imageUrl: url, placeHolderImage: image)
```

[SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Comment: @AnilkumariOSdeveloper as you need with global function. I have created a struct you can reuse it.

Comment: I am looking for only image, not imageview.setimage

Comment: `SDWebImage` is `UIImageView` extension,  It work as  `imageView.sd_`,  You can check all the details in GitHub link(provided in answer)

Comment: Then, you can go ahead with load image with `URL` with `DispatchQueue` or [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage)